# How can I switch to a particular version of Android after I checkout out the source code?

Tags: android

If I check out the android source code like this:

```
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
```

How can I switch to a particular version of android ? e.g. 1.6?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html:

```
To check out a branch other than "master", specify it with -b:
$ repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b froyo
```

Comment: So I can do a 'repo init -u git ... -b froyo' after I did a 'repo init -u git ...'